# How to access Share Point Site as API using Python

Tags: python, api, sharepoint

I am trying to access share point site as api using python to download files.

So far I have tried "shareplum" , "office365", and "sharepy" modules in python.

Every time I am getting authentication error due to invalid username or password.

But I can logon to that share point site from web browser using same username and password.

What approach should I follow or what sort of authentication should I use ?

Regards
Santanu

shareplum:

```
from shareplum import Site, Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
import json
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config_path = '\\'.join([ROOT_DIR, 'config_1.json'])

with open(config_path) as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
    config = config['share_point']

USERNAME = config['user']
PASSWORD = config['password']
SHAREPOINT_URL = config['url']
SHAREPOINT_SITE = config['site']
SHAREPOINT_DOC = config['doc_library']


def auth():
    authcookie = Office365(SHAREPOINT_URL, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD).GetCookies()
    print(f"authcookie: {authcookie}")
    site = Site(SHAREPOINT_SITE, version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
    print(f"site: {site}")
    return site


def connect_folder(folder_name):
    auth_site = auth()
    print(f"auth_site: {auth_site}")
    sharepoint_dir = '/'.join([SHAREPOINT_DOC, folder_name])
    print(f"sharepoint_dir: {sharepoint_dir}")
    folder = auth_site.Folder(sharepoint_dir)
    print(f"folder: {folder}")
    return folder


def download_file(file_name, folder_name):
    _folder = connect_folder(folder_name)
    print(f"_folder: {_folder}")
    return _folder.get_file(file_name)


def run():
    # set file name
    file_name = 'Hardy_ServiceReporting_Aug2021.csv'

    # set the folder name
    folder_name = 'Problem Management'

    # get file
    file = download_file(file_name, folder_name)
    print(file)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Error: `Error from Office 365:', 'AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.'`

office365:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import json
import os


ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config_path = '\\'.join([ROOT_DIR, 'config_1.json'])

with open(config_path) as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)
    config = config['share_point']

USERNAME = config['user']
PASSWORD = config['password']
SHAREPOINT_URL = config['url']
SHAREPOINT_SITE = config['site']
SHAREPOINT_DOC = config['doc_library']
FOLDER = "Problem Management"

url = SHAREPOINT_SITE + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{}/{}')/Files".format(SHAREPOINT_DOC, FOLDER)
print(f"url: {url}")
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
print(f"ctx_auth: {ctx_auth}")
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
print(f"ctx: {ctx}")
```

Error: `An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance.`

Comment: Is MFA enabled in your tenant?

Comment: I am new to share point, so please elaborate. what do you mean by MFA ? how can we check that ?

Comment: It's Multi-Factor Authentication. When you logon to the site, you could use phone for authentication instead of usename and password.